# Maven cucumber reporting from eclipse not generating the reports as per this plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Trying to generate the reports as per the maven cucumber reporting 
[Link to maven cucumber reporting](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting)

Made the necessary changes in the pom.xml file as explained here [tutorial on configuring reports](https://damienfremont.com/2016/05/09/how-to-cucumber-test-report-plugin-2-with-maven-and-java/)

But the reports are getting generated in the simple html file but not as per the cucumber reports.

pom.xml

```
   <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.${java.version}</source>
                        <target>1.${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore> -->
                        <includes>
                            <exclude>**/*RunCukesTest.java</exclude>
                            <!-- <include>**/*RunCukesTest.java</include> -->
                        </includes>
                        <!-- <excludes> <exclude>**/*RunCukesTest.java</exclude> </excludes> -->
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- This is for Cucumber Custom Report plug in we specify the configuration 
                    details under configuration tag. -->
                <!-- http://startingwithseleniumwebdriver.blogspot.com/2016/05/custom-cucumber-reporting-using-maven.html -->
                 <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                    <version>3.11.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>execution</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <projectName>CucumberReport</projectName>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
                                <!-- <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput> -->
                                <jsonFiles>
                                    <param>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</param>
                                </jsonFiles>
                                <!-- <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting> -->
                                <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
                                <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
```

RunCukesTest.java

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"classpath:features"},
        plugin = {"html:target/site/cucumber-pretty","json:target/cucumber.json"},
        tags = {"@currentTest"},
        glue={"helpers","stepDefinitions"},
        monochrome = true
        )
public class RunCukesTest{

}
```

Reports are generated like this
[image: generated report]

which are different from expected
[image: expected report]

Comment: Do not make links to images better put text into post...

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks. will follow

Comment: how do you run the script? using maven command or using runner class?

Comment: @Murthi Tried both. but mostly using mvn using `mvn test`, `mvn test verify`, `mvn clean test verify`

Comment: mvn verify should work. make sure, script is running and json file is generated.

Comment: @Murthi tests are getting executed successfully. json is getting generated but not the cucumber report. Are there any configuration mistakes i'm doing?

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy The parallelTesting configuration is extra in your config. Not mentioned in the demo link

Comment: i don't find any issue in configuration. I am using the verison. 3.6.0. It is working fine. i am not tried with latest version.

Comment: @Grasshopper removing the 'parallelTesting' doesn't make any difference. Same surefire html is generated.

Comment: @Murthi i tried with 3.6.0 as well. no difference.

Comment: As per document, <!-- cucumber output parameter is deprecated, use jsonFiles instead --> , you may try with json file option.

Comment: @Murthi i did try that one as well. Commented in the pom file shared above

Comment: are you using plugin management or just plugins in maven?

Comment: @Murthi plugin management, updated the pom file in the question

Comment: don't use plugin management, just use plugins.

Comment: @Murthi Yes this worked. Reports are getting generated. But when i executed same feature is displayed twice where it actually ran once. And can you help me understand why plugin management caused this issue

Comment: plugin management is used for concept of multi modules in you  projects. if you don't have multi module , it may not works properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161517/discussion-between-nagarjuna-reddy-and-murthi).

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy You need to format the result as pretty formate and integrate or source of jenkins plugin this result generate file path.

Comment: @BostonStar reports are getting generated after removing the tag `pluginManagement`. But features are getting generated twice, so i can see each feature twice in the reports

Comment: @Murthi `<jsonFiles<param>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</param></jsonFiles>` this is generating the duplicate reports. so using `<cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>`. Finally reports are working. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all configuration was good,
made two changes.

1. removed `pluginManagement` tag in pom
2. Used `cucumberOutput` output directory instead of `jsonFiles`. For some reason `jsonFiles` was generating duplicate reports.

pom file,

```
      <build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.3</version>
             <configuration>
                <source>1.${java.version}</source>
                <target>1.${java.version}</target>
             </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.20</version>
             <configuration>
                <includes>
                   <exclude>**/*RunCukesTest.java</exclude>
                </includes>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
             </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
             <version>3.13.0</version>
             <executions>
                <execution>
                   <id>execution</id>
                   <phase>verify</phase>
                   <goals>
                      <goal>generate</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                      <projectName>Simplify360 Automation Test Report</projectName>
                      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>                      
   <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                      <buildNumber>8.4.1.2</buildNumber>
                   </configuration>
                </execution>
             </executions>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 1):

POM.XML::

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
         <configuration>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            <includes>
            <include>**/TestRunner.java</include>
            </includes>
         </configuration>
     </plugin>


   <plugin>
  <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
<version>4.5.0</version>
  <executions>
  <execution>
  <id>execution</id>
  <phase>test</phase>
<goals>
 <goal>generate</goal>
 </goals>
<configuration>
<!--   <projectName>imademethink_cucumber_advanced_reporting</projectName>  -->
 <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/cucumber-reports-advanced</outputDirectory>
 <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
 <skippedFails>true</skippedFails>
 <enableFlashCharts>false</enableFlashCharts>
<!--  <buildNumber>885</buildNumber> --> 
<buildNumber>8.4.1.2</buildNumber>
 </configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>        










 </plugins>
 </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set flag as below

```
<checkBuildResult>true</checkBuildResult>
```

Find my answer in below question URL

[Reports are not generated when the build is failed in Maven Cucumber Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904644/reports-are-not-generated-when-the-build-is-failed-in-maven-cucumber-reports/52206782#52206782)

Answer (score 0):

Just make 2 changes, and there you go

1. remove the tag  from pom.xml file.
2. provide the version explicitly for the maven-surefire-plugin.
   ex:version: 2.22.1